# How to Pull Data more efficiently using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

I've just inherited a data collection tool for a church newsletter and parishioner contact information collection. Included in a long list of data points are polling questions that they'll use to decide on a mobile app to build to keep parents up to date on family events. I haven't coded in years and need help in optimizing what I've inherited.

This code exists in a single HTML file that a user accesses as expected through a web browser.

I have a table with data collection points and optional text input fields that a user would work with to enter collected values. The values are taken from the various inputs and put into a template. There are 45 such values. They are arranged as such:

```
    <table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <td class="col1"><input type="radio" id="noancheck" value="" name="a1" checked></td>
        <td class="col2"><input type="radio" id="ancheck" value="" name="a1"></td>
        <td class="col3">Android Device Identifier</td>
        <td class="col5">&android_id=</td>
        <td class="col4"><input type="text" id="android_id" size ="45" value="" placeholder="INSERT_ANDROID"></td>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1"><input type="radio" id="noecheck" value="" name="a2" checked></td>
        <td class="col2"><input type="radio" id="echeck" value="" name="a2"></td>
        <td class="col3">App Activity Type</td>
        <td class="col5">&etype=</td>
        <td class="col4"><input type="text" id="etype" size ="45" value="" placeholder="INSERT_EHEAD"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1"><input type="radio" id="noicheck" value="" name="a3" checked></td>
        <td class="col2"><input type="radio" id="icheck" value="" name="a3"></td>
        <td class="col3">Apple Device Identifier</td>
        <td class="col5">&idfa=</td>
        <td class="col4"><input type="text" id="apple" size ="45" value="" placeholder="INSERT_APPLE"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1"><input type="radio" id="nobcheck" value="" name="a4" checked></td>
        <td class="col2"><input type="radio" id="bcheck" value="" name="a4"></td>
        <td class="col3">Brand</td>
        <td class="col5">&brand=</td>
        <td class="col4"><input type="text" id="brand" size ="45" value="" placeholder="INSERT_BRAND"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="line">
        <td class="col1"><input type="radio" id="noccheck" value="" name="a5" checked></td>
        <td class="col2"><input type="radio" id="ccheck" value="" name="a5"></td>
        <td class="col3">Category</td>
        <td class="col5">&cat=</td>
        <td class="col4"><input type="text" id="model" size ="45" value="" placeholder="INSERT_MODEL"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For each of the 45 data points, a var is declared similar to what follows:

```
var android_out = document.getElementById('android_id').placeholder +     document.getElementById('android_id').value;
var ehead_out = document.getElementById('ehead').placeholder +    document.getElementById('ehead').value;
var apple_out = document.getElementById('apple').placeholder + document.getElementById('apple').value;
var brand_out = document.getElementById('brand').placeholder + document.getElementById('brand').value;
var model_out = document.getElementById('model').placeholder + document.getElementById('model').value;


var js_1 = 'List Item';
var js_2 = 'Inventory';
var js_3 = '\');';
var kvp_1 = '&';
var kvp_2 = '=';
```

When a button is clicked, the following executes and fills the collected data into a template that's displayed in a textarea:

```
document.getElementById("formoutput1").innerHTML = 'beginning of data collection template' +
    android_id_string +
    ehead_id_string +
    apple_id_string +
    brand_id_string +
    model_id_string+
    'end of data collection template';

document.getElementById('formoutput2').innerHTML = 'beginning of second template'
    android_id_kvp +
    ehead_id_kvp +
    apple_id_kvp +
    brand_id_kvp +
    model_id_kvp +
    'end of second template';
```

Given there are up to 45 data points being collected each time this is used, the code is rather long. How can this be optimized? I'm having a difficult time applying what I've learned about loops to this and would deeply appreciate an example that I can extrapolate from.

Comment: Have you thought about using [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) or [Wufoo](http://www.wufoo.com/) or some other mechanism? Not what you asked but it might be nice not to deal with long complex forms.

Comment: My initial thought was 'can't we do this through like Google Docs?" but, the folks who I'm volunteering for say that they can't use any third party tool or service for this as a matter of policy.

Comment: A loop might help if it's the same for all of them… And use an object with properties (so that you can programmatically access them by name) instead of 45 variables.